# php Jquery form generated from a foreach

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a foreach that generate data from an sql select. When user click on the div a text message appears "points ganed" and the data inside the form will be submitted.

The entire script works but it always submit the last form on 4 generated... he doesnt target the right form.

There's a way to anchor the right form to submit? thanks in advance to all.

```
<script>
function(response) {

                $('#mydiv').text('Points gained');                                   
                $("#form").submit()


 }</script>

 foreach ($usermeta as $post) {

 <form method="post" id="form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

 <div id="mydiv">

 click here to earn points.

 </div>

 <input type="hidden" name="points" id="points" value="<?php echo $post->points; ?>"                         class="regular-text" />

 </form>

 }
```

Comment: the problem is with form id, becouse you used same id for all forms (BTW this not valid w3c standard), the solution is to use $(this).parents("form:first").submit(), but i think you should give each form unique ID at anyway

Answer (score 0):

Every single form has the same id.  You need to make sure the id of the form is unique.

I don't have enough rep to comment, but this is what you could do.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.mydiv').click(function() {
            $(this).text('Points gained').closest('.form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<?php foreach ($usermeta as $post): ?>

<form method="post" class="form" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <div class="mydiv">
        click here to earn points.
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="points" class="points" value="<?php echo $post->points; ?>" class="regular-text" />
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: hello and thanks for the answer, since sql generate user ids by points i use $post->user_id that correctly give me the ids. then i change  $("#form<?php echo $post->user_id").submit() and id="form<?php $post->user_id; ?>"> and the foreach generate form1 form2 form3 ... but the script can target the right.. and always submit the last form........

Comment: I tried your way but doesnt work, always submit the last form and text appear on the last div... :( thanks you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like this,

before the foreach i decleare that

```
 $i = 1;
```

then

```
<form class="<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

then at the end of form but before the foreach end tag

```
$i ++;
```

so now i have

```
<form class="1">
<form class="2">
<form class="3">
<form class="4">
```

and so on, then i put a limit of display element from the sql select putting limit 10.